# jQuery append text formatting

Tags: javascript, jquery

This question is not related to coding issues but how we write our codes. For example take the append function. When we use jQuery append to insert long divs, it is easy to lose track of it's correctness. Example:

```
$('#someDiv').append('<div><span><div> .............. hundreds of div here ..... </div></span></div>');
```

Is it possible to convert this to a readable format, for example using multi-lines. I tried

```
$('#someDiv').append('<div>'+
+'<span>'+
+'<div> ...... and you get the point')
```

This doesn't seem to work. This question may be easy for some but it is not so obvious for me. Also although I minify js files at the end, it would be nice **not** to lose track of the elements while writing the code.

Comment: _doesn't seem to work_ ? is there any error ?

Comment: You have a `+` followed by a `+`. This is syntactically correct but expect to find a couple of `0`s and `NaN`s in your HTML.

Comment: @SalmanA yup that is what happened

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it this way -

```
$('#someDiv').append($('<div>').append($('<span>'))
                               .append($('<div>'))
                               .append($('<div>'))
                               .append($('<div>'))
                               .append($('<div>'))
)
```

You can also add `css`  styles, add class, change html while appending these *html elements (wrapped in jQuery object)*

```
$('<div>').css('color','red')
$('<div>').addClass('someClass')
$('<div>').html("and you get the point")
```

Answer (score 5):

If you have to add the HTML inline style I would suggest the following format.

```
var html =
'<div class="somediv">\
  <div class="otherdiv">\
    .
    ..
    ...
  </div>\
</div>';

$('#somediv').append(html);
```

Comment: This is adding too many spaces in between newlines. Any suggestions?

Comment: You could make it less human-readable by dropping the indention.

Answer (score 0):

My solution would be to create all these elements

```
div1 = $(document.createElement('div'));
div1.attr(..);
div1.css(..);


container.append(..)
```

This means a lot of code but you can outsource it, can easily change attributes and its good readable...